# How to upgrade to "Google for Work" from current Google account?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

When I try to apply for "Google for Work", it asks me to create a new account for the business plan. It seemed only logical to me that I should be able to "upgrade" my current account to a business account. This way I can have my 5 years of email archive and activity on other Google services and my new account in one place. I can't seem to find the solution for this. Is this possible?

Comment: Do your Google account has a @gmail.com address or a custom domain as primary email address?

Comment: @Rubén My primary email address is [at]gmail but I was looking for a way to merge my Google Apps account with my gmail account. BTW thanks for your response.

Answer (score 4):

Google consumer accounts can't be upgraded to a Google Apps account, but if a Google consumer account use as primary email address one from a custom domain a conflicting account will be created. During the signup process for that account, Google will offer the user to migrate some of the data.

**References**
[Resolve conflicting accounts - Google Apps Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/185186?hl=en)